# Catch exceptions from walking a file tree

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to walk a file tree using `Files.walkFileTree()`, but unfortunately some of the files on a shared, network drive cannot be read from my host. That is fine, the only problem is that I do not know how to actually protect against such an exception... The `walkFileTree()`tries to generate a directory stream, but fails there due to the file it can't read... Is there any other way I can walk the file tree easily and catch any such exceptions?

Comment: I think the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree) mentions that `Files.walkFileTree()` throws `IOException if an I/O error is thrown by a visitor method`. This means you can catch the `IOException` in your visitor to solve your problem. If there is a problem reading the file or its attributes, then your visitor's method `visitFileFailed` will be called. There you should return `FileVisitResult.CONTINUE`.